# Listen for Phone State changed, two different way: BroadcastReceiver and TelephonyManager

Tags: android

Why to get phone state changed status, android provides two way: BroadcastReceiver with action android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE, and using TelephonyManager with a PhoneStateListener ?

There is a substantial difference on the contents? or change only the method of notification?

I could register a listener with TelephonyManager.listen(PhoneStateListener listener, int events) and handle state in onCallStateChanged(), or alternatively register a BroadcastReceiver for action android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and handle event in onReceive().

Why and when to prefer one or the other way?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that `TelefonyManger` works within applications.
Make sure to not instantiate it yourself.
You should use it with :

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
```

This would seem useful if you plan on making a dialer application which directly can make phone calls or use other features of the phone **directly within your application**

On the other hand, if you register a `BroadcastReceiver`, this means you want to know about the phone state even **when your application is not in the foreground**. Possibly if you were making an application that was tracking phone usage.

[TelephonyManager on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)